# STL algorithm for splitting a vector into multiple smaller ones based on lambda

Tags: algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

Let's say I have a vector containing a struct with a member describing its target vector.

```
struct Foo
{
  int target;
  static const int A = 0;
  static const int B = 1;
  static const int C = 2;
};

std::vector<Foo> elements;

std::vector<Foo> As;
std::vector<Foo> Bs;
std::vector<Foo> Cs;
std::vector<Foo> others;
```

Now I want to move each Foo in one of the four other vectors based on the value of Target.

For example

```
auto elements = std::vector<Foo>{ {Foo::A}, {Foo::A}, {Foo::B} };
```

Should result in two elements in `As`, one in `Bs` and none in `Cs` or `others`. `Elements` should be empty afterwards.

I could as well do it myself, but I wonder if there is an STL algorithm I could use to do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard algorithms usually don't operate on multiple output destinations, so it's hard to come up with a suitable solution here when you want to abstract away the destination containers through output iterators. What might come closest is `std::copy_if`. This could look like

```
// Help predicate creation:
auto pred = [](int target){ return [target](const Foo& f){ return f.target == target; }; };

std::copy_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::back_inserter(As), pred(Foo::A));
std::copy_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::back_inserter(Bs), pred(Foo::B));
std::copy_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::back_inserter(Cs), pred(Foo::C));
std::copy_if(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::back_inserter(others),
    [](const Foo& f){ return false; /* TODO */ });

elements.clear();
```

If copying is more expensive than move-construction, you should pass `std::make_move_iterator(elements.begin())` and the same for `elements.end()` to the algorithm. The issue here is that this doesn't scale. `std::copy_if` linearly traverses the input range, and the above has to do this four times. One traversal can be obtained e.g. like the following.

```
auto doTheWork = [&As, &Bs, &Cs, &others](const Foo& foo) {
   if (foo.target == Foo::A)
      As.push_back(foo);
   else if (foo.target == Foo::B)
      Bs.push_back(foo);
   else if (foo.target == Foo::C)
      Cs.push_back(foo);
   else
      others.push_back(foo);
};

std::for_each(elements.begin(), elements.end(), doTheWork);
```

In this scenario, we have at least employed a standard algorithm, but shifted the logic into a rather ugly lambda. Note that the above lambda will always copy its arguments, it needs some adjustments to properly work with `std::move_iterator`s.

Sometimes, a good old range based for loop is the most readable solution.

Comment: I guess so, I've searched through <algorithm> and couldn't really find something taking multiple iterators. I've now sticked to the for loop, thank you :-)